# Autofilter PHPExcel

Tags: filter, phpexcel, autofilter

I have an excel file who contains filter in a row.

I convert my excel file to HTML Table like that :

```
        $excel = glob(''.$path'.{xlsx,xls,xlsm,xlsm.ink}', GLOB_BRACE);
    $filterSubset = new \PHPExcel_Reader_DefaultReadFilter('A','N');
    $objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($excel[0]);
    $objReader->setReadFilter($filterSubset);
    /**  Read the list of worksheet names and select the one that we want to load  **/
    $worksheetList = $objReader->listWorksheetNames($excel[0]);
    $sheetname = $worksheetList[0];
    /**  Advise the Reader of which WorkSheets we want to load  **/
    $objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetname);
    /**  Load $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  **/

    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($excel[0]);

    ### HERE I DONT KNOW WHAT TO DO ###

    $autoFilter = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getAutoFilter();
    $autoFilter->showHideRows();

    var_dump($autoFilter);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter('A1:N1');

    ### HELP ME PLEASE ###

    $writer = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, "HTML");
    $writer->generateStyles();
    $writer->generateSheetData();
```

I just wanna know how to apply and display my filters. range('A1:N1') .

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set Autofilter, you need to set the full range of data, not simply the headers; but Autofilter is only provided for native Excel formats only, and not available for HTML

Comment: Anyway i cant do that ?

Comment: Not through PHPExcel's HTML Writer, you'd have to write your own